# Flutter Login Api Rest JWT

Tags: flutter, login, jwt, auth

estoy empezando a desarrollar con flutter y no tengo mucha idea de como crear un Login, he estado investigando mucho. Mas no me ha quedado claro como es que debo de hacer el login en base a lo siguiente:

Bueno en estos momentos tengo dos peticiones POST las cuales una me regresa Token de acceso, claro en siempre y cuando el email sean correctos:

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VybmFtZSI6ImdhanVhcmV6ZGVsYWMiLCJuYmYiOjE2MDU3NDA3NjQsImV4cCI6MTYwNTc0MTM2NCwiaWF0IjoxNjA1NzQwNzY0LCJpc3MiOiJJRE0uQVBJIiwiYXVkIjoiSURNV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb24sTVZDV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb24ifQ.bcRFYC2KnaGNFlg11ebj_NRiBMIPamkOBzCZtu0-9xc",
"expires_in": 600,
"token_type": "Bearer",
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y  en la otra se recibe el token de la primera petición(key) y de igual manera en el cuerpo se requiere el email y el password.

```
{
"IsAuthenticated": true,
"UserMessage": null,
"ResultMessage": "Inicio de sesión correcto",
}
```

Alguien me podría explicar y o bien dar un ejemplo como puedo guardar el token y luego usarlo para autenticarme con el email y el password, claro una vez recibido el Token.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias, de antemano.

Comment: La respuesta puede variar en base a la estructura que lleves de tu proyecto y de la administración de estado, y por lo regular en un login el token lo obtienes hasta que se validan tus contraseñas,

Comment: Puedes guardar el token en las preferencias compartidas https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences ya la llamas cada que quieres hacer otra petición que requiera JWT

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es guardar ese token en el localstorage y luego llamarlo e incluirlo en cada petición que realices al servidor, no se sabe que backend  estes usando pero generalmente en la primera petición se envía usuario:password y el servidor responde con un JWT que debes enviar en las futuras peticiones sin necesidad de enviar de nuevo las credenciales.

Te recomiendo echarle un ojo a estos dos plugins que te sirven para lo que necesitas:

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
https://pub.dev/packages/encrypted_shared_preferences

Te recomiendo usar el segundo que tiene mas seguridad